# Closed form representation of an exponential series

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $t\in\mathbb{R}\ge 0$ and consider the following series

$$
f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\exp({-a^2 t})-\exp({-n^2 t})}{n^2-a^2} .
$$

The series is well defined in the poles at $n=a$ in the sense that the limit exists. The series is zero at $f(0)=0$ and for $t\to\infty$ we have $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t) = 0$.

I am interested in a closed form expression of the series in terms of the exponential function (if possible at all) or in terms of Polygamma/Polylogarithm functions. I have searched in "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by I. S. Gradshteyn, but came up empty.

Does a closed form representation exist?